# How to write unit test for mongotemplate operations

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I have created spring boot micro service post API. where I am inserting bulk documents inside mongodb using mongoTemplate.bulkOps(BulkOperations.BulkMode.UNORDERED, xyz.class);
I wanted to test this functionality through unit test using some mock db how can I achieve this could some one give a pointer??

Answer (score 0):

Use [embedded mongo](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo) and create [@DataMongoTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/data/mongo/DataMongoTest.html) test class.

something like

```
@DataMongoTest
class BulkDocumentRepositoryTest {

  @Autowired
  private BulkRepository bulkRepository;
  
  @BeforeEach
  void init() {
    bulkRepository.deleteAll();
    // or something else if you need
  }

  @Test
  void performSomeTestHere() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi @bilak,  I am not using BulkRepository. When my REST api is called (controller) I In turn call service where my implementation exists(of contacting to db BulkOperations.execute() ) so How could I write test case to test the whole flow ?? the one you showed is just to play with database for eg: delete and insert. But here I want to write unit test at-least for service class.

Comment: that was just an example...if you need to test controller or service with db, then you probably want integration test and spin-up whole application context. For sure you can use that embedded mongo. It's hard to follow what you need